# importancia de paréntesis cuando uso #define

Tags: c

En el siguiente codigo si yo no pongo parentesis a la multiplicacion D1, cuando imprimo D2 dice que este tiene un valor de 5, si yo los pongo me imprime correctamente 4, porque ocurre eso ?

```
#define D1 3*2 
#define D2 D1-2

int main()
{
}
```

Answer (score 3):

> Si yo no pongo parentesis a la multiplicacion D1, cuando imprimo D2 dice que este tiene un valor de 5, si yo los pongo me imprime correctamente 4

Tendrás que añadir tu código, porque mis pruebas no muestran ese comportamiento; sin añadir paréntesis a `D1` obtengo 4:

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define D1 3*2 
#define D2 D1-2

int main()
{
    printf("%d", D2); // Imprime 4.
    return 0;
}
```

Esto es consistente con la [precedencia de operadores en C](http://es.cppreference.com/w/c/language/operator_precedence):

1. `++` (sufijo), `--` (sufijo), `()`, `[]`, `.`, `->`.
2. `++` (prefijo), `--` (prefijo), `+` (unario), `-` (unario), `!`, `~`, `(cast)`, `*`, `&` (unario), `sizeof`, `_Alignof`.
3. `*`, `/`, `%`.
4. `+`, `-`.
5. `<<`, `>>`.
6. `<`, `<=`, `>`, `>=`.
7. `==`, `!=`.
8. `&` (And a nivel de bit).
9. `^` (Xor a nivel de bit).
10. `|` (Or a nivel de bit).
11. `&&` (And lógico).
12. `||` (Or lógico).
13. `?:` (Operador ternario)
14. `=`, `+=`, `-=`, `*=`, `/=`, `%=`, `<<=`, `>>=`, `&=`, `^=`, `|=`.
15. `,`;

Veremos que la multiplicación tiene una precedencia mayor (3ª) que la resta (4ª), por lo que si tenemos estas definiciones:

```
#define D1 3*2 
#define D2 D1-2
```

Tras pasar el preprocesador tendremos que `D2` es:

```
3*2-2
```

Si aplicamos las normas de precedencia equivale a:

```
(3*2)-2
```

Que resulta en `6-2`, que es `4`.

Si la resta tuviera preferencia sobre la multiplicación, **el resultado no sería 5**:

```
3*2-2
```

Equivaldría a:

```
3*(2-2)
```

Que resultaría en `3*0` que es `0`.